# Override name of inherited Bean

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

Is it possible to override the bean name of an inherited abstract class?

E.g. I got a abstract class with a Bean method. Now I want to set a specific name for the Bean if I extend it. Is this possible and how?

```
@Configuration
abstract class AbstractConfig {

  @Bean
  open fun foo(): Foo {
    // ....
  }

}
```

```
@Configuration
class myConfig: AbstractConfig() {

  @Bean("myFoo")
  override fun foo(): Foo {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have an abstract Configuration class? What exactly is your use case?

Comment: @JoãoDias Context is: I want to implement multiple (mongodb) database Configurations using the existing AbstractMongoClientConfiguration Class. So the Abstract Config has some methods with autowired arguments and I want to adapt on some settings. And the accessor to the Database (MongoTemplate) should have a different name for each Configuration (in this case `myFoo`) so I can easily autowire the needed Mongotemplate.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to connect to multiple MongoDBs?

Comment: @JoãoDias Exactly

Comment: In that case you need to register the Beans programatically.

Answer (score 0):

In the above example, when making Autowired/Inject you will always get the override implementation (you will never get the one in the abstract class).
If you want to be able to get several implementations you can add several methods that creates Foo, each one will create another implementation and will have another bean name.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can't do that. If you want to connect to multiple MongoDBs you need to create and register the Beans programmatically with `GenericApplicationContext.registerBean()` method. You can find more details about this at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-beans.